# pandas: Perform multiple commands with a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, pandas

I have the following data:

```
    url='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/108michael/ms_thesis/master/clean_gdp_data_all.csv'

c=pd.read_csv(url, index_col=0)
c = c.loc[(c.GeoName == 'California') & \
           (c.ComponentName == 'Real GDP by state')]
c.head(3)


    GeoName     ComponentName   IndustryClassification  Description     2004    2005    2006    2007    2008    2009    2010    2011    2012    2013    2014
38281   California  Real GDP by state   111-112     Farms   15717   18751   18215   15335   14109   18798   19197   16535   15014   16909   0
38282   California  Real GDP by state   113-115     Forestry, fishing, and related activities   6234    6278    7845    7786    7365    7390    7831    8115    8995    9312    0
38284   California  Real GDP by state   211     Oil and gas extraction  7769    8107    10693   12342   12010   17155   14575   15289   18849   16165   0
```

I want to run the following code with a for loop, except that I want to run it for every year (2004-2014) and then merge them all together, as indicated in the last line of code:

```
    d = c.sort_values('2004', ascending=False).head(10)[['GeoName', \
'IndustryClassification', 'Description', 'ComponentName', '2004' ]]


e = c.sort_values('2005', ascending=False).head(10)[['GeoName', \
'IndustryClassification', 'Description', 'ComponentName', '2005' ]]

crgdp = pd.merge(d,e, how='inner', on=['GeoName', \
'IndustryClassification', 'Description', 'ComponentName'])
```

Comment: Why does your reference to your data frame keep switching between `c` and `d`?

Comment: @brittenb: Thank you for your comment. I just updated the code.

Comment: @MaxU: Thanks for the comment! Yes, I could do that. This problem is  a little more complicated I need to perform this merge for every `GeoName` and for every `ComponentName`. I am sorting for every year separately as I need the top 10 industries' per year. I could sort the data, per year, into 11 different dfs. I could also break up the `raw-file` by `GeoName`and `ComponentName`. However, I don't know how to do that nicely with pandas.

Comment: @MaxU: I have opted for setting up a template that collects all states/years per `ComponentName` and just switching out `ComponentName`; but, I will clean all my code later into the project. Right now I am prioritizing results over eloquence. It has been over 2 months and I am still wrestling with my data. I have less than 4 months left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can't do this in the way you want to do it because all values in one row are "connected" and belong to that row. So you can sort your DF by one column, which will reorder all rows with all corresponding values, but next time when you will sort another column - you'll lose sorted order in the first column and so on...

Look at index values and at values in `a` and `b` columns in the following example:

```
In [16]: df
Out[16]:
   a  b  c
0  0  7  1
1  6  6  0
2  7  4  5

In [17]: df.sort_values(by='a', ascending=False)
Out[17]:
   a  b  c
2  7  4  5
1  6  6  0
0  0  7  1

In [18]: df.sort_values(by='b', ascending=False)
Out[18]:
   a  b  c
0  0  7  1
1  6  6  0
2  7  4  5

In [19]: df.sort_values(by=['a','b'], ascending=False)
Out[19]:
   a  b  c
2  7  4  5
1  6  6  0
0  0  7  1
```

**NOTE:** doesn't matter how do we sort our data all values in each row are "bound" to each other and to their index.

So you can either sort your DF by `a` or by `b` or by `['a','b']`, but in this case your `b` column will **not** be monotonically decreasing.

And looking at your data - if you would group your data by your "merging" columns and check for duplicates you would see that you don't have any of them:

```
In [132]: c.groupby(['GeoName', 'IndustryClassification', 'Description', 'ComponentName']).size().nlargest(3)
Out[132]:
GeoName     IndustryClassification  Description       ComponentName
California  ...                     Federal civilian  Real GDP by state    1
                                    Federal military  Real GDP by state    1
                                    State and local   Real GDP by state    1
dtype: int64
```

It shows that each group has exactly one row. So after merging all your rows will remain the same, because you can consider `['GeoName', 'IndustryClassification', 'Description', 'ComponentName']` columns as a primary key (i.e. unique identifier).

Here is an example:

```
In [125]: c.query("GeoName == 'California' and IndustryClassification == '111-112' and Description == 'Farms' and ComponentName == 'Real GDP by s
tate'")
Out[125]:
          GeoName      ComponentName IndustryClassification Description  \
38281  California  Real GDP by state                111-112       Farms

          2004     2005     2006     2007     2008     2009     2010     2011  \
38281  15717.0  18751.0  18215.0  15335.0  14109.0  18798.0  19197.0  16535.0

          2012     2013  2014
38281  15014.0  16909.0   0.0
```

Comment: Thank you MaxU. I understand what you mean with the sorting issue. Invariably, some industries will have missing values since they are not in the 'top 10' for every year (that is also why I chose 10 instead of a smaller sub-section). My concern is that if I only sort for one ( or two) year(s), and since I am controlling for the effect of 'top-industries' (as measured by GDP contribution per state) on 'industry-related bill-sponsorship', the question may be raised 'was this industry a top contributor for every year'.

Comment: However, your post is helpful. I only need to do the sort for `Real GDP` I can then use a `group by` that includes the sectors that are relevant. So, again you have contributed to my gradual progress. Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelPerdue, if i understand your task correctly, you can do it separately for every year or for all years altogether, but it would be easier then to work with _unpivoted_ data, IMO

Comment: Yes, that is correct; I haven't intentionally executed a pivot on any of the data. I have only cleaned it a bit (take out unwanted columns and rows) after downloading it, before uploading to GitHub. Maybe if I 'unpivoted' the data it would be easier to work with.

Comment: @MichaelPerdue, if you want to unpivot your `c` DF: `pd.melt(c, id_vars=['GeoName', 'IndustryClassification', 'Description', 'ComponentName'], value_vars=c.filter(like='200').columns.tolist(), var_name='year', value_name='GDP')`
`

Comment: Thank you! That is where I should have started. It would have saved me a lot of grief. I'm still new to data handling and 'research' in general. This project has been a crash course in Python and data-manipulation. At every step I am learning something new s.t. it is hard to tell if I am making any progress. But, in Dec. I was learning how to use the `print` function; so, I guess something is there.

Comment: @MichaelPerdue, one can easily see your great progress by the questions you are asking :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110074/discussion-between-michael-perdue-and-maxu).

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, it shall help you to get forward:

```
import pandas as pd

url='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/108michael/ms_thesis/master/clean_gdp_data_all.csv'
c=pd.read_csv(url, index_col=0)
d = c.loc[(c.GeoName == 'California') & (c.ComponentName == 'Real GDP by state')]
for y1, y2 in zip(c.columns[4:], c.columns[5:]):
    d1 = d.sort_values(y1, ascending=False).head(10)[['GeoName','IndustryClassification', 'Description', 'ComponentName', y1 ]]
    e1 = d.sort_values(y2, ascending=False).head(10)[['GeoName','IndustryClassification', 'Description', 'ComponentName', y2 ]]
    crgdp = pd.merge(d1,e1, how='inner', on=['GeoName','IndustryClassification', 'Description', 'ComponentName'])
    crgdp.to_csv('{0}-{1}.csv'.format(y1,y2), index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment and suggestion! I'm going to see what I can do with this :)